# How to correct join issue?

Tags: sql

I'm having a SQL issue that is driving me crazy, but I'm sure the solution is pretty simple.  I have data that is similar to the sample below, where volume is summarized by account per month.  However, an account may have zero volume for certain months, in which case there is no record present for that month.

```
month        acct#      volume
05/2018       1234        33
06/2018       1234        20
08/2018       1234        26
01/2018       2345        40
02/2018       2345        60
03/2018       2345        20
```

I need every account number to show all 12 months for 2018, even if there is no volume (and therefore no record present).  As an example, for account 1234, it would look like this:

```
month        acct#      volume
01/2018       1234        0
02/2018       1234        0
03/2018       1234        0
04/2018       1234        0
05/2018       1234        33
06/2018       1234        20
07/2018       1234        0
08/2018       1234        26
09/2018       1234        0
10/2018       1234        0
11/2018       1234        0
12/2018       1234        0
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  I've tried a number of things, but there is no point in trying to explain them here because none of them are getting me any closer to the solution.  My first thought was to create a separate table with the 12 months and do a left outer join, but this still doesn't fix the issue when no record is present (i.e. for account 1234 no join happens on April since there is no volume and therefore no record).

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your separate table is a good first step. Imagine the query `SELECT DISTINCT salestable.acct#, monthtable.month FROM salestable, monthtable` That should give you EVERY acct# with EVERY month. From there you can LEFT OUTER JOIN to your existing query.

Comment: You could use a cursor and loop through the months. If you go with a months-table you could do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT` to get all rows, or create the months table in the query `FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ...) months`

Comment: @JNevill this century you'd probably use `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generate the rows with a `cross join` and bring in the values using `left join`.

If your data contains all the months of interest, you can use it:

```
select m.month, a.acct#, coalesce(t.volume, 0) as volume
from (select distinct month from t) m cross join
     (select distinct acct# from t) a left join
     t
     on t.month = m.month and t.acct# = a.acct#;
```

If your data does not have all months of interest, then you need to define `m` manually in some way.  That depends on the database.

Comment: This worked!  I guess I'll have to learn more about CROSS JOIN as I'm still not clear on how it worked.  Thanks!